# Words pertaining to the senses and the corresponding disabilities

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, adjectives, vocabulary, sense-verbs

I need help on finding words relating to the senses/perception. I mean this in a neuronic/biological or philosophy-of-mind kind of way.

A word for...

- pertaining to the senses (Is it *sensory*?)
- pertaining to vision (*ocular*?)
- pertaining to smell (*olfactoric*?)
- pertaining to taste
- pertaining to sound
- pertaining to touch
- unable to smell
- unable to taste
- unable to feel/touch
- unable to perceive (*unconscious*?)
- (unable to see: *blind*)
- (unable to hear: *deaf*)

Comment: You've listed the 5 commonly-understood senses, but there are generally considered to be between 9 and 21 human senses, including such things as the vestibular sense and proprioception.  Are you also looking for words describing those senses?

Answer (score 34):

Words relating to the "senses/perception" in a "neuronic/biological" context:

- pertaining to the senses: [*sensory*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/medical/sensory)
- pertaining to vision: [*ocular*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/medical/ocular) or [*optic*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/medical/optic) or [*visual*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/medical/visual)
- pertaining to smell: [*olfactory*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/medical/olfactory)
- pertaining to taste: [*gustatory*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/medical/gustatory)
- pertaining to sound/hearing: [*auditory*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/medical/auditory) or [*aural*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/medical/aural) or [*acoustic*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/medical/acoustic)
- pertaining to touch: [*tactile*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/medical/tactile) or [*tactual*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/medical/tactual) or [*haptic*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/medical/haptic)
- unable to feel/touch: [*anaptic*](http://www.medterms.com/script/main/art.asp?articlekey=11292)
- unable to smell: [*anosmic*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/medical/anosmic)
- unable to taste: [*ageusic*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/medical/ageusic)
- unable to perceive: [*insentient*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/insentient) or [*unconscious*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/medical/unconscious) or other pertinent synonym

---

* *All but two of the links take you to the [Merriam-Webster Medical Dictionary](http://www.merriam-webster.com/medical/), so you can confirm the definitions. My search for "anosmic" and "ageusic" took me to the [National Institute on Deafness and other Communication Diseases](http://www.nidcd.nih.gov/health/). Finally, I found the root of "anaptic" ("aphia") on this page, which happens to have a host of other words you might find useful (some of which are already in this list): [Terms for Cognitive, Behavioral and Neurologic Disorders](http://dubinweb.com/brain/a2.html)*.

Comment: There is a distinction to be drawn between words for the sensory organs and words for the senses. *Ocular* does not refer to vision, but to the eyes, and would be analogous to terms like *otological* (of the ear), *rhinological* (of the nose), *glossal* (tongue), and *digital* (fingers and toes).

Comment: Tactile is very specific; perhaps you'd consider replacing it with somatosensory?

Comment: I have seen the word *kinesthetic* to mean of or relating to touch; it is the adjectival form of this word:

*kinesthesia*, n. awareness of the position and movement of the parts of the body by means of sensory organs (proprioceptors) in the muscles and joints.