# a word like "visual", "auditory", except for touch

Tags: single-word-requests, sense-verbs

for smell it would be "olfactory". What is it for touch?

Comment: Related question: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7256/pertaining-to-the-senses

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Hah [Google Sets](http://labs.google.com/sets) was actually useful for something! Results for inputting visual, olfactory, and auditory were:

- visual
- olfactory
- auditory
- gustatory
- tactile
- kinesthetic
- vestibular
- proprioceptive
- pain
- touch/pressure
- gravity
- receptors
- kinaesthetic
- somatosensory

So, tactile it is!

Comment: "Haptic" is sometimes used as well in some technical contexts, but will not be understood by most people (i.e. I had to look it up when I first encountered it).