# Ways to perceive something: textually, visually, acoustically?

Tags: adverbs

Textual describes something as being in text form. I can read something that is textual. Something that is visual can be viewed. I can listen to something that is acoustical in nature? I don't think acoustical is the right word. What word am I looking for?

Comment: [Also related](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7362/a-word-like-visual-auditory-except-for-touch).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"auditory" may be the apt word. The acoustical is related to the study of sound.

Comment: Acoustics is the study of vibrations, waves, and frequency. It covers phenomena that exist outside of auditory perception.

Comment: It need not be out side the auditory perception..the acoustics of a auditorium take into consideration the absorption of sound by audience or reflection of sound by walls etc..

Comment: Indeed. Sound falls under the umbrella of vibrations and waves. I only wanted to point out that acoustics is a broader subject than just sound. I should have said it also covers phenomena that exist... or that it includes phenomena that exist... I didn't mean to suggest that you were wrong, I sought only to expand on the definition you had provided.

Answer (score 1):

The word you are looking for is auditory.

Answer (score 0):

It can be "Auditory" or "Aural"