# A word for 'relating to taste'

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, analogy

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Pertaining to the Senses](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7256/pertaining-to-the-senses)

*Sound* is to *aural* as *smell* is to *olfactory* as *touch* is to *tactile* as *taste* is to... what?

I can't think of a word that describes the sense of taste. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Wikipedia says [**gustatory**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taste).

And from Oxford dictionary

> gustatory; concerned with tasting or the sense of taste

Comment: damnit, I just found it :D