# "Vision" is to "visually", as "hearing" is to what?

Tags: single-word-requests

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Pertaining to the Senses](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7256/pertaining-to-the-senses)

Hello. If I want to say my project has great graphics, I say it is *visually stunning*.

Now, what would I say, following a similar format to that, if my project had great "audio/sounds/"?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Technically probably "aurally", perhaps "audibly" would be better — or just "stunning audio".

Comment: **Aurally** seems right to me here, not **audibly**.  *Aurally stunning* means its aural aspects are stunning; *audibly stunning* would mean you can hear that it’s stunning.

Comment: Aurally is correct but how many people would know? And how many would jst snigger?

Comment: +1: I was also going to say "aurally".

Comment: Aurally is correct, but I wonder how many people would think that you meant an assault on [their invisible emanations](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/aura).

Comment: Aurally may actually be correct, but quite apart from the unavoidable connotations with invisible emanations, there's also confusion with *orally* in speech.

Comment: That's why "audibly better" (is that Dolby's logo?) might be better even if not specifically correct

Comment: "Audibly" comes off better for all the reasons described, however I believe the visual analogy to it is "visibly", not "visually" as the question dictates.  It really depends on how nit-picky you want to be.

Comment: Aurally is the answer, nothing else.

Answer (score 9):

If it is visibly stunning, then it should

> **Aurally stunning**

Comment: Snerk.  I assume it's a typo, but "visibly stunning" _(can be seen to be stunning)_ would be matched by "audibly stunning" _(can be heard to be stunning)_.

Comment: Idiot: As Rhodri points out, OP asked for a word corresponding to *visually*, not *visibly*.

Answer (score 7):

"Auditorily" seems to fit well.

Comment: Nice one! Incredibly rare word, so much so that Webster thinks its often just a mis-spelling of **auditorly** (for 'like an auditor', would you believe!)

Answer (score 6):

I would say "acoustically", since Merriam-Webster defines acoustic as " relating to the sense or organs of hearing, to sound, or to the science of sounds".