# Read, write, speak and?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

Saying "I can read XXX" is precise in referring to the ability to understand only written text. Saying "I can understand XXX" could refer to either reading or understanding audio. Is there a single word that means only the ability to understand audio?

Comment: I could have sworn we got this question before.

Comment: I did expect to find this in a search but nothing came up.

Comment: Is "written text" redundant?

Comment: On exams, the listening section is the one that tests audio comprehension.

Comment: @Sam depends on what you're taking written to mean (e.g. hand written). In this context it certainly seems redundant.

Comment: @simchona: do you mean [this one](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7256/pertaining-to-the-senses)?

Comment: @reg--no, there was one by a user who was asking how to explain his language competency. Like he could understand only speaking? I don't remember who it was.

Comment: @Pete In my opinion, this question has not received a definitive answer. I wonder if it's possible it is based on a faulty premise. Or, perhaps I just mean the answer is _no_, there is single word to fulfill the role you define.  I'm going to reread the answers and if none seem to say this, I'll post this as an answer. (If I can post a second answer.)

Comment: @Pete: It may be better to refer to 'speech'/ 'spoken' than 'audio', if that's what is intended in the OP. That may help better understand the question in that case.

Comment: Not single-word, but you could say "I can understand spoken XXX"

Answer (score 3):

In the context of learning a language, we often speak of being able to *read*, *write*, *speak* and *listen* to it.

Comment: _Listen_ doesn't stipulate understanding. I can _listen_ to someone speaking French, but, unfortunately, I have no ability to understand it.

Comment: Perhaps, *listen*, as opposed to just *hear*, implies hearing with (an attempt at) comprehension.

Comment: Yes, I agree. But an _attempt_ to understand may fail. The OP asks for a word that corresponds to _read_. I don't think _listen_ quite does. Though the OP does mention the _ability_ to understand_, we don't say a person can _read_ if they can't understand the text. But one can _listen_ and not understand, no? _Hear_, as Gnawme suggests, has a meaning of comprehension, not just an attempt. It's a tricky one, isn't it! It would help to hear from the OP, but it appears he's _distracted_.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't "I can understand ....." referring to the fact that one has the ability to understand audio/spoken words/sentences?

We often use, I can read/write/speak to differentiate between the abilities to read/write/speak.

My best bet for ability to understand audio, in common usage is on "I can understand...."

Answer (score 1):

To complete the phrase with grace: Read, write, speak, and *hear*.

The word *hear* is so common that we take it for granted, and forget that it specifically means:

> to be made aware of by the ear : apprehend by the ear

where *apprehend* itself means

> to lay hold of with the understanding : recognize the existence or
>   meaning of

[All definitions Merriam-Webster Unabridged]

Comment: _Hear_ is a step closer than _listen_, but I don't think it is commonly understood to necessarily indicate understanding.

Comment: There's the word's _connotation_, with which I agree with your point; and there's its _denotation_ -- its actual meaning -- which I've supplied in my revised answer.

Comment: *Hear* can also mean a simple perception sound, but I think it's meaning will be clear in context.  If one says "Listen; do you hear French?" it should be taken differently than if one says "I can hear French, but I cannot speak it."  However, it still sounds awkward to my ear.

Comment: @sarah you are not being consistent. The person asking the question said "read" means "understanding" so in that context, "hear" is the analog.

Answer (score 1):

*Write, read, speak and . . . ?* The only word that fits is *understand*. I know that *understand* can be used of writing as well, but the context will almost always show what is meant.

Comment: But the OP asks for _a single word that means *only* the ability to understand audio_.

Answer (score 1):

The OP notes that one is said to *read* if one can *understand* written text.

He adds, somewhat superfluously I think, that one can *understand* information provided in written or audio form.

The OP then asks for:

> a **single word** that means only the ability to understand audio

I think the answer is *no*, there is no single word primarily understood to mean that. I'm with Gnawme that *hear*  does have that meaning, certainly more so than *listen*, which was also suggested, and would fit most elegantly into the role.

However, I don't believe that particular meaning of hear is limited to information received via audio. For instance, one might respond to sentiments expressed in an email with the reply, *I hear you*.

Primarily, though, the problem I see is that  *hear* is so much more commonly used and understood to mean simply : [to perceive or apprehend by the ear](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hear). To *hear* audio would then pair more closely with to *see* written information, rather then to *read* it.

Answer (score 0):

"*Speak*" implies both speaking and listening abilities in this context, with the presumption that one could not speak without being able to understand the spoken word by listening.

I am probably the only exception, though.

So, you can just say *I can speak* to mean both speech and listening abilities. That covers the entire "audio" domain. The converse is not true! One could understand reasonably well listening to people, but be unable to speak in the language.

Comment: One can certainly be able to speak a language intelligibly, and not understand a word of it when the language is spoken at normal speed. In fact, I believe this often happens with Americans in certain parts of the U.K.

Answer (score 0):

*[Auditory Discrimination](http://Auditory%20discrimination%20refers%20to%20the%20brain%27s%20ability%20to%20organize%20and%20make%20sense%20of%20language%20sounds.)* is defined by Wise Geek as *the brain's ability to organize and make sense of language sounds*. However, it is generally understood to mean something closer to [this](http://www.education.com/definition/auditory-discrimination/) from education.com: [the] *Ability to distinguish sounds of varying frequencies, intensities, and patterns,* which reflects a more accurate meaning of *discrimination*.

*[Auditory Processing](http://www.bbbautism.com/auditory_processing_disorder.htm)* is *the ability to listen, comprehend, and respond to information that we hear through our auditory channels,* according to bbbautism.com.

[A similar definition](http://www.speech-therapy-on-video.com/stroketerms.html) is provided by speech-therapy-on-video.com: *the ability to hear auditory messages, distinguish between similar sounds or words, separate relevant speech from background noise, and the ability to recall and comprehend what was heard.*

Unfortunately, for your purposes, this is not a single word. But it's pretty close.

Comment: *Auditory* has to do with the perception of hearing -- not *audio* in the sense of 'sound', which includes both speech and hearing. It seems the OP relates to a broader faculty of an ability to speak and to listen (and understand therefrom).

Comment: Hmm, not sure I take your point. Isn't all audio processed through the sense of hearing? I'm not saying my answer is correct, though. I'm beginning to think the premise of the question is faulty. I'll try to explain that in a separate comment.

Comment: Again, two words, so not what the OP requested, however, both of my linked definitions for _auditory processing_ specifically include _the ability to comprehend information that is perceived thorough our sense of hearing._ What is understanding if not comprehending? And what is audio if not _information that is perceived thorough our sense of hearing_? Sorry, I know your comment was meant to explain this, but I don't think it does.

Answer (score -1):

Being able to read something doesn't imply being able to understand it. And there is a difference between understanding the words themselves and understanding the meaning.  The analog of reading is listening.  By the same token, I can listen to someone, it doesn't mean I know what they're talking about.

Comment: It does weakly imply it. If I said "I can read Japanese", you would assume I could understand what I was reading.

Comment: _Reading_, at least in educational contexts (and, I think in general), does imply understanding. If one is not understanding, one is not _reading_.

Comment: I suppose it does _imply_ understanding in one sense, but understanding is a vague notion with many levels. "Colorless green ideas sleep furiously". In a one sense, I understand this sentence. It is grammatically correct, but it is meaningless. How can you understand a meaningless sentence? That doesn't mean I can't read it.

Comment: @Sam I do see your point. However, this is a special case because there is no meaning intended in the sentence. Nothing _to_ understand. So, in terms of my (and the OP's) claim that _reading_= understanding, I guess I would claim you _can't_ actually _read_ that _sentence_. I'd argue that you can, however, _read_, each of the words, since each, alone, does have meaning.