# Corresponding Descriptive Word For Unable To Distinguish Flavors

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, analogy

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Pertaining to the Senses](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7256/pertaining-to-the-senses)

If colorblind is a descriptive word for people who cannot distinguish colors and tone deaf describes people who cannot distinguish one tone from another, is there a similar word for someone is unable to distinguish between one taste and another?

Comment: I suffered taste loss for several months last year two weeks into what would have been a 6-month course of [lamisil](http://www.healthboards.com/boards/ear-nose-throat/448576-taste-loss-due-lamisil.html). It was incredibly difficult to convey to anyone just how distressing and restrictive the condition is! Now I just feel sorry for my cat, having since learnt that all domestic cats have lost the ability to detect sweetness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Ageusic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ageusia) describes a loss of taste, which would correspond to deafness and blindness.

[Dysgeusic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dysgeusia) describes alteration of taste, which could correspond to tone-deafness and colorblindness.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to suggest *[palate-dull](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/palate)* where palate is

> b : the sense of taste

Comment: Upvoted even though I wasn't really looking for a neologism--looking for an existing word. :-)