# Medical term for deafness

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, analogy, medical

- Anosmia = Loss of the sense of smell
- Anopia = Blindness
- Anaesthesia/Anaphia = Loss of the sense of touch
- Ageusia = Loss of taste
- ?       = Deafness

I can't find an equivalent medical term for deafness. Is there one? I also find that the word 'deafness' suffers from a dearth of synonyms that do not involve the word 'deaf'.

Also, if there are terms that are more apt for the loss of the other traditional senses, please list them as well.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Words pertaining to the senses and the corresponding disabilities](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7256/words-pertaining-to-the-senses-and-the-corresponding-disabilities)

Comment: Not a dupe—that question isn't asking for a **medical** term for *deaf*.  It accepts *blind* for inability to see and *deaf* for inability to hear.  This question is asking whether there's a corresponding medical term for deafness.  Basically, *blindness:anopia::deafness:what*?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The suffix *-acusis* pertains to hearing, and is normally combined to form words like *[presbycusis](http://encyclopedia.thefreedictionary.com/presbycusis)* (*presby* + *acusis*, age-related hearing loss) and [*paracusis*](http://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/paracusis) (*para* + *acusis*, any hearing impairment).

When you combine the *an-* prefix (meaning *not* or *without*) with *-acusis*, you get *[anacusis](http://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/anacusis)* -- deafness.

Comment: +1 Perfect!  And [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anacusis) is the wikipedia link.  I'll recognize it in my answer, if you don't mind, but this is the one that should be accepted.

Comment: Nice one! Cheers :)

Comment: **Anakusis** is the preferred spelling in medical dictionaries (*Dorland's Illustrated Medical Dictionary*, 30th Ed., *Saunders Comprehensive Veterinary Dictionary*, http://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/anakusis).

Comment: @JLG Interesting; in [your last reference](http://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/anacusis) (which is linked to my answer), it says "anacusis _or_ anakusis."

Comment: @JLG: Stedman's prefers anacusis and Mosby's has only that.

Comment: @Gnawme, I don't see that when I follow my link.(Not sure why?) *Dorland's* and *Saunders Vet* dictionaries don't list *anacusis* at all. *Dorland's* lists it as an alternate spelling to *anakusis*. *Dorland's* does have: "*anacousia*: anakusis."

Comment: Fun fact: "akouo" (ἀκούω) is ancient Greek for "I hear".

Comment: @Kalamane And that's why "the suffix *-acusis* pertains to hearing".

Comment: @Danielδ Exactly. :)

Answer (score 2):

<s>*Deafness* is the best single word you'll find, I think, though *hearing impairment/loss* is probably more common in the medical world.</s>

***[Anacusis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anacusis)*** (from [Gnawme's answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/75133/10041)) is a medical term that means *complete deafness*.  
<sup><sub>[I'm only recognizing it here - he came up with it first.  Please accept his answer.]</sub></sup>

For your list, there's *[ageusia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ageusia)*, the loss of the sense of taste, which should probably replace *aphasia*, since speech isn't a traditional human sense.

Answer (score 1):

Following the pattern of *anosmia* and *anopia*, the equivalent for hearing would be *anauria*, from *aural*.  Unfortunately, I can't find any evidence that it's an established word.

Comment: Yeah, I tried Googling that already, but it mostly only brings up references to [a land in the Forgotten Realms](http://forgottenrealms.wikia.com/wiki/Anauria).

Comment: Alas, I've been guilty of mixing a Greek prefix with a Latin root. Gnawme's *anacusis* looks much better.

Answer (score 0):

There is no all encompassing word for hearing loss other than deafness. This is because there a simply too many types of hearing loss.

Look here for a few of those http://ehealthmd.com/content/different-types-hearing-loss

Comment: Thanks :) There are many types of blindness too. Yet, we have words like _anopia_ and _amaurosis_ as potentially generic terms along with terms for particular cases such as _nyctalopia_, _achromatopsia_ etc. It's odd that deafness alone does not carry words with a Latin root and from what I can tell nor do the various types of deafness.

Comment: I stand corrected by the answers above me. My search fu was bad yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

Deafness, hearing impairment or hearing loss; all of these can be used in cases of partial or complete, temporary or permanent loss of hearing.